# get rid of the outer tag using golang and regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I am using the goalng to do some template,and want to get rid of the outer  tag .
as the following:

```
  input := `aaa<div><dxh r="4" spans="1:15"><c r="A4" s="7"><v>{{4567}}

</v></c><c r="B4" t="s" s="7"><v>11</v></c><c r="C4" t="s" s="7"><v>12</v>

</c><c r="M4" t="s" s="8"><v>20</v></c></dxh>aaa</div>bbb<dxh>{{12345}}

</dxh>amrambler`
```

and i want to get the string. it ommit the tag `"<dxh ....>"`,`"</dxh>"` . and only remain the content between them, `"{{4567}}"` and `"{{12345}}"`

```
str=`aaa<div>{{4567}}aaa</div>bbb{{12345}}amrambler`
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get your desired output.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?s)<dxh[^>]*>.*?({{[^}]*}}).*?</dxh>")

    input := `aaa<div><dxh r="4" spans="1:15"><c r="A4" s="7"><v>{{4567}}
              </v></c><c r="B4" t="s" s="7"><v>11</v></c><c r="C4" t="s" s="7"><v>12</v>
              </c><c r="M4" t="s" s="8"><v>20</v></c></dxh>aaa</div>bbb<dxh>{{12345}}
              </dxh>amrambler`

    res := re.ReplaceAllString(input, "$1")
    fmt.Println(res) // aaa<div>{{4567}}aaa</div>bbb{{12345}}amrambler  
}
```

<kbd>[**GoPlay**](http://play.golang.org/p/PdOEt0_ayf)</kbd>